# Not getting the height of the status bar when using custom drawer header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am stuck kind of. I wanted to create a customer head for my drawer. Was planning to do something similar to what we see with Reddit. The problem I am running into are two different ones.

1 - If I try to add a `<SafeAreaView />` I get a lot of padding/margin to the bottom. I will attach an image to the bottom to show what I mean.

2 - If I don't use the wrapper then we have the statusbar overlapping the team (also will attach the image). I am not seeing any mention about the status bar height within the properties given.

If anyone has a better approach for the problem I am having, I am open to hear any advice. My main goal is to have a custom head.

Will provide the code as well for this block of code

```
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="testingit"
    component={TabNav}
    options={{
      header: (props) => {
        console.log(props);
        const open = () => {
          console.log("opening");
          props.navigation.openDrawer();
        };
        return (
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "yellow",
              margin: 0,
              padding: 0,
            }}
          >
            <Text onPress={open}>Hellow</Text>
          </View>
        );
      },
    }}
  />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I found the solution a few minutes after posting.

```
export const CustomSafeAreaView = (props: any) => 
  <SafeAreaView edges={['top', 'left', 'right']}>{props.children}</SafeAreaView>
```

This also goes to create toward the person who mention this solution here https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/167#issuecomment-758264492